# how can I get a signal from SQLite3 when the db is edited?

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite

I have two programs working like daemon/clients, the daemon manages a database, and I would like the deamon to signal to the clients when some modification has been done at the database by the daemon itself (1) or by command from a client (2) AND also if I'm using the SQLite's command line shell (3) .

for cases (1) and (2) I see a way to do that, for example when I edit some value somewhere I can tell it to the clients.

for case (3) I'm looking for some signals functions attached to the database. Moreover, using some signal function like one who signals everytime a cell has ben edited can be used for all cases.

there is such things in SQLite c/c++ api ?

Comment: No. And then some more text to make this comment long enough to be accepted by this site.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams well, in that case I will have to think to write a signal from scratch...

Comment: You can use the fairly recent [`data_version` pragma](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_data_version) to check if the databases was modified, but it won't tell you what about it was modified. You could also set something up with triggers that insert into a revision log table.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo for cases (1) and (2) I think I should be able to wrtte some signal(s). For (3) using `data_version` would require to read the value every frame and if new and old `data_version` are different to reload the DB in each client... quite ugly stuff... I also thought to use `GFileMonitor` to monitor the database... But I think I will change my strategy, I think I will protect (basic encryption maybe) the file against case (3), in other words, I won't let anybody else than the daemon to change that db when the daemon is running... by that, I will avoid some messy stuffs...